# Can someone help me extract substrings from this text?

Tags: java, json, api, data-extraction

I am trying to create a project for which I  need to extract data from imdb. I've seen some of the php extractors but I  need a java program to that. 
I need to extract information like:

1. Movie name and year
2. Small plot
3. Rating
4. Genre
5. Actors

The data is below from which I need to extract data:

```
{
    "Title": "Brave",
    "Year": "2012",
    "Rated": "PG",
    "Released": "22 Jun 2012",
    "Runtime": "1 h 40 min",
    "Genre": "Animation, Action, Adventure, Comedy, Family, Fantasy",
    "Director": "Mark Andrews, Brenda Chapman",
    "Writer": "Mark Andrews, Steve Purcell",
    "Actors": "Kelly Macdonald, Billy Connolly, Emma Thompson, Julie Walters",
    "Plot": "Determined to make her own path in life, Princess Merida defies a custom that brings chaos to her kingdom. Granted one wish, Merida must rely on her bravery and her archery skills to undo a beastly curse.",
    "Poster": "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMzgwODk3ODA1NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNjU3NjQ0Nw@@._V1_SX640.jpg",
    "imdbRating": "7.5",
    "imdbVotes": "1,002",
    "imdbID": "tt1217209",
    "Response": "True"
}
```

This data is from imdbapi.com if it helps.
Let me know if there are any other ways to extract this data in any other manner, i mean some other way by which this data will be shown in more structured form. Like excel.

Comment: Looks like JSON. Use GSON or Jackson.

Comment: I would consider JSON to be more structured than Excel, but that's just me...

Answer (score 2):

It's JSON.  Use a JSON library to parse it.

http://www.json.org/

Answer (score 2):

It looks [JSON](http://json.org/example.html) to me. Get a JSON parsing library.

Comment: I must have been typing then. It's all yours ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This is valid JSON (validated it [here](http://jsonlint.com/)). Use the [JSON in Java](http://www.json.org/java/) library. [Here's an example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/) of parsing json.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, looks like houman001 and I were a slow on the draw ;)

Answer (score 2):

As this is a JSON String You can use JSON Passer to extract the information from your data. You can populate above information in to JAVA Object using JSON parser. 
refer following link.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library